# Dummy Array Value for Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, unit-testing

If have this error in unit testing wherein it cant detect the `id`:

```
claim.claimReference[claim.claimId[claim.claimants[0].id]]
```

Currently, I am trying to put a dummy value for this

```
claim: {
     claimReference: [{
      claim: {
        claimId: [
          {
            claim: {
              claimants: [{
                id: "CM-0000003",
              }],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }],
  },
```

What is my mistake in here? Thank you for your correction.

EDIT: OHH WAIT. I THINK MY QUESTION WAS MISUNDERSTOOD. SORRY.
PLEASE SEE THE IMAGE ATTACHED.

[ERROR IN UNIT TESTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjdS5.png)

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO IS TO HAVE A DUMMY VALUE SO THAT I COULD SATISFY THE `claim.claimReference[claim.claimId[claim.claimants[0].id]]`

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
claim.claimReference[0].claim.claimId[0].claim.claimants[0].id
```

Comment: Please reread [answer] and then [edit] your answer to explain *why* this works. Always keep in mind that you're not only solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers on why this works.

Comment: SORRY. I THINK MY QUESTION WAS MISUNDERSTOOD. PLEASE SEE THE EDITED VERSION.

Comment: There are no claimants[0].id and claimId on claim obj. There's only claimReference